# Evolving Product Backlog vs. Release Burndown

Tags: scrum

According to Roman Pichlers "Agile Product Management with Scrum"

"[...] we prepare just enough [backlog] items for the upcoming sprint, just in time."

IMHO this includes, among other things, estimating the story points of the respective backlog items.

At the same time "[the release burndown] is based on the following two factors: the remaining effort in the
product backlog, and time."

IMHO this two statements are contradictory because we don't know the story points of all backlog items
at the beginning or during a sprint.

Please can somebody help me with this?

Thank you in advance

Andi

Comment: better ask at programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: You may have a look at these links: http://codebuild.blogspot.com/2011/08/10-scrum-methodology-best-practices.html http://codebuild.blogspot.com/2011/08/scrum-software-development-methodology.html

Comment: This question is off-topic because it's not within the scope for this site, as defined in [What topics can I ask about here?](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Also see: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](//stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) You may be able to ask on [another Stack Exchange site](//stackexchange.com/sites#name), for example [pm.se] or [softwareengineering.se]. Be sure to read the on-topic page in the help center for any site on which you intend to post a question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [project management is now off-topic on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343829/is-stack-overflow-an-appropriate-website-to-ask-about-project-management-issues/343841#343841). Ask these questions on [SoftwareEngineering.SE](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and [ProjectManagement.SE](//pm.stackexchange.com/) instead. (Unfortunately, this question is too old to be  migrated.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A story must be expressed as story points before it's taken into sprint, these points are summed up to see when you planned enough for one sprint. You also need to points in order to maintain a velocity going from sprint to sprint.

It's fine to do some rough pre-estimating of backlog items though. This helps the product owner do some release planning and prioritizing ahead of a spring planning meeting. It also helps creating a release burn down chart (in combination with the team's velocity).
The rough estimates may be re-estimated during a sprint planning meeting where there are usually discussed in full detail.